# Union Select - Heavy CPU Loading

Tags: mysql, select, union, cpu-usage

i'm facing a major issue here with this sql query:

```
select
`produsereceptie`.`receptie_id` AS `document_id`,`receptie` AS `receptie`,
`produsereceptie`.`produs_id` AS `produs_id`,
`produse`.`cod` AS `cod`,
`produse`.`denumire` AS `denumire`,
`produsereceptie`.`gestiune` AS `gestiune`,
sum(`produsereceptie`.`qty`) AS `qtyIn`,
ifnull((select sum(`productie`.`qtyConsumat`) FROM `productie` where (`productie`.`produs_id` = `produsereceptie`.`produs_id`) group by `produsereceptie`.`produs_id`),0) AS `qtyOut` 
from (`produsereceptie` join `produse` on((`produse`.`id` = `produsereceptie`.`produs_id`))) 
group by `produsereceptie`.`produs_id` 
union select `comenzimonitorizari`.`idx` AS `document_id`,
'productie' AS `productie`,`produse`.`id` AS `id`,
`produse`.`cod` AS `cod`,`produse`.`denumire` AS `denumire`,
'productie' AS `productie`,sum(`comenzimonitorizari`.`produse_conforme`) AS `qtyIn`,
ifnull((select sum(`produseiesire`.`qty`) from `produseiesire` 
where (`produseiesire`.`produs_id` = `produse`.`id`) 
group by `comenzimonitorizari`.`produs_cod`),0) AS `qtyOut` 
from (`comenzimonitorizari` join `produse` on ((`produse`.`cod` = `comenzimonitorizari`.`produs_cod`))) 
group by `comenzimonitorizari`.`produs_cod`;
```

the sql explain is in the attached image ( http://postimg.org/image/vysy9i6ab/ )

any help is most welcome, because I dont know how to optimize it.

the average time is around 9-10 seconds... and i'm facing infernal here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try UNION ALL instead of UNION. Hope it helps

**UPDATE**

I can't test over the data, but i will say that the problem is with this line:

```
ifnull((select sum(`productie`.`qtyConsumat`) FROM `productie` where (`productie`.`produs_id` = `produsereceptie`.`produs_id`) group by `produsereceptie`.`produs_id`),0) AS `qtyOut`
```

First try remove this query replacin-it with something like

```
0 AS `qtyOut`
```

How are you times now?

Comment: unionall : Showing rows 0 - 29 (119 total, Query took 3.9395 sec)

Comment: union: Showing rows 0 - 29 (119 total, Query took 3.9902 sec)

Comment: How are your indexes defined? How many records the tables has?

Comment: please take a look at the explain : http://postimg.org/image/vysy9i6ab/ you will find all the rows there. and, regarding the index: there are index defined for all the join elements: product_id, comanda_id, product_code, and so on ...

Comment: WOW - you are a genius.... Showing rows 0 - 29 (119 total, Query took 0.0079 sec) - let's see how I can replace that sum()... and I'll get back with the update ! thanks a lot

Comment: The problem is that you are using a WHERE statement instead of a JOIN. Try to re-formulate the query to use a JOIN. Remember to mark the answer. Good luck!